# How do I use sendmessage for sending wm_timer that has timer proc in win32

Tags: winapi, timer, sendmessage

I have a timer, ID 1, which has a timerproc as a callback function.

I am making the other timers (ID 2, 3, ...) in the timerproc and they use `WM_TIMER` event, not another timerproc.

When creating window, I want to immediately generate Timer Event, ID 1.

So I used SendMessage function like that

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_TIMER, 1, (LPARAM)&timerproc);
```

but it didn't work.

How do I activate timerproc at right that the first time of window?

```
void CALLBACK MakeRain(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, UINT_PTR wParam, DWORD lParam) 
{ /* this is timerproc for ID 1 */
    if (gRdx >= MAX_WORDS_COUNT) return;

    gRain[gRdx].f = 1;
    gRain[gRdx].x = rand() % (gRect.right - 30);
    gRain[gRdx].y = 10;

    int id = RdxToTID(gRdx);
    int vel = rand() % 2000 + 1000;
    SetTimer(hWnd, id, vel, NULL);    /* In here I am making other timers */
    gRdx++;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        HDC hdc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        int tid = wParam;
        int rdx = TIDToRdx(tid);

        switch (iMessage)
        {
        case WM_CREATE:
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &gRect);
            srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
            SetTimer(hWnd, 1, MAKE_RAIN_TERM, MakeRain);
            /* my trying, It is not working */
            //SendMessage(hWnd, WM_TIMER, 1, (LPARAM)&MakeRain);
            return 0;
        case WM_TIMER:
            gRain[rdx].y += 10;
            if (gRain[rdx].y >= gRect.bottom) {
                gRain[rdx].f = 0;
                KillTimer(hWnd, tid);
            }
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS_COUNT; i++) {
                if (gRain[i].f == 0) continue;
                TextOut(hdc, gRain[i].x, gRain[i].y, words[i], lstrlen(words[i]));
            }
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            KillTimer(hWnd, 1);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, iMessage, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Comment: As I know that TimerProc function's lParam means the address of TimerProc function.

Comment: This sound slike an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you _actually_ trying do do? With `SetTimer(hWnd, 1, MAKE_RAIN_TERM, MakeRain);` is `MakeRain` called or not?

Comment: Definitely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Besides that, there are at least 2 bugs waiting to happen: `1` The assumption that timers will expire at accurate intervals is unfounded. If you write your animation code with that assumption, it will look jagged. `2` The timer ID is pointer sized. Use that feature to guard against ID collisions, e.g. by using the address of a (global) object as the timer ID.

Comment: If you want `MakeRain` to be called imediately, don't use magic, just call it.

Comment: Thank you for providing the right amount of code to find the problem.

Comment: Now I know what the XY problem is, It seems exactly the XY problem, and also It is solved, I didn't know that It can be called even CALLBACK function, Thank you :) I can see the words rain now! at the time starting app!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When creating window, I want to immediately generate Timer Event, ID 1.
>   So I used SendMessage function like that
>
> ```
> SendMessage(hWnd, WM_TIMER, 1, (LPARAM)&timerproc);
> ```
>
> but it didn't work.

The callback gets called by the timer only when the timer signals the owning thread's message queue to generate a `WM_TIMER` message, which is then retrieved by `(Peek|Get)Message()` and passed to `DispatchMessage()` by the thread's message loop.  It is `DispatchMessage()` that calls the timer callback if one is assigned, otherwise it delivers the `WM_TIMER` message to the window's WndProc:

> If the `lpmsg` parameter points to a `WM_TIMER` message and the `lParam` parameter of the `WM_TIMER` message is not `NULL`, `lParam` points to a function that is called instead of the window procedure.

Using `SendMessage()` bypasses the window's message queue and goes directly to the window's WndProc.  That is why you are not seeing the timer callback getting called.

So, at the very least, you would have to use `PostMessage()` instead of `SendMessage()` so that your manual `WM_TIMER` message can go through the window's message queue and reach `DispatchMessage()`:

```
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_TIMER, 1, (LPARAM)&timerproc);
```

Otherwise, you would have to call `DispatchMessage()` directly with a fake `MSG` of your own:

```
MSG msg = {};
msg.hwnd = hWnd;
msg.message = WM_TIMER;
msg.wParam = 1;
msg.lParam = (LPARAM) &timerproc;
msg.time = GetTickCount();
GetCursorPos(&msg.pt);
DispatchMessage(&msg);
```

However, that is not actually necessary, because...

> How do I activate timerproc at right that the first time of window?

The callback is a function, so just call it directly, like any other function:

```
//SendMessage(hWnd, WM_TIMER, 1, (LPARAM)&MakeRain);
MakeRain(hWnd, WM_TIMER, 1, GetTickCount());
```

Comment: Of note `WM_TIMER` is generated in the queue handling functions, a timer never actually causes it to be queued.  "The message is posted by the GetMessage or PeekMessage function."  So calling `PostMessage` would not replicate the timer actually firing (although it maybe would reach the same handler)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. The timer sets a flag in the queue, and then message retrieval checks that flag and generates a fake `WM_TIMER` message if there are no higher priority messages in the queue. That fake message then reaches `DispatchMessage()` like any other message, and DM will either call the timer callback or deliver the message to the window's WndProc. Manually posting a `WM_TIMER` message does not "fire the timer", but it does cause the posted `WM_TIMER` message to come out of the message queue and reach `DispatchMessage()` the same way as a generated `WM_TIMER` message.

Comment: Raymond Chen blogged about how `WM_TIMER` messages get generated: [If my WM_TIMER handler takes longer than the timer period, will my queue fill up with WM_TIMER messages?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141204-00/?p=43473) and [Why is my message queue full of WM_TIMER messages?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160624-00/?p=93745).