# How/Why does KillTimer invalidate existing WM_TIMER messages?

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, timer, windows-messages

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765273/6609896) to a question about how to schedule a TIMERPROC to run immediately. I was interested in this as I need to run a method immediately after the caller has finished executing its code synchronously.

So I came up with this skeleton:

```
Private Sub asyncProc(ByVal HWnd As LongPtr, ByVal message As WindowsMessage, ByVal timerID As LongPtr, ByVal tickCount As Long)
    Debug.Print "asyncProc called (should be called second)"
End Sub

Private Sub syncProc()
    Debug.Print "syncProc called (should be called first)"
End Sub

Sub test()
    If tryScheduleProc(AddressOf asyncProc, New Collection) Then
        syncProc
    Else
        Debug.Print "Unable to schedule proc"
    End If
End Sub
```

... and of course the next step was to design the `tryScheduleProc` function, which would setup a call to `asyncProc` with a unique id provided by the address of the `New Collection` Object (in practice this would be the callback's arguments).

## Tests

My first approach was to copy the method set out in the linked answer; namely to post a `WM_TIMER` message to the `Application.HWnd`'s message queue:

```
Private Function tryScheduleProc(byVal timerProc As LongPtr, ByVal arg As Object) As Boolean
    Debug.Print "Scheduling..."
    tryScheduleProc = PostMessage(Application.HWnd, WM_TIMER, objPtr(arg), timerProc)
End Function
```

However that prints

```
Scheduling...
syncProc called (should be called first)
```

i.e. the `asyncProc` is never called.

---

Thinking there might be something wrong with the message I switched to the traditional way of generating timer messages, `SetTimer`, only this time with a very short delay:

```
Private Function tryScheduleProc(ByVal timerProc As LongPtr, ByVal arg As Object) As Boolean
    Debug.Print "Scheduling..."
    Debug.Print "Create Timer:"; SetTimer(Application.HWnd, objPtr(arg), 0, timerProc)
    tightLoopDelay 100 'wait 100ms for timer to have elapsed definitely
    
    Dim tempMsg As tagMSG
    tryScheduleProc = PeekMessage(tempMsg, Application.HWnd, WM_TIMER, WM_TIMER, PM_NOREMOVE) 'force message to be posted
    KillTimer Application.HWnd, objPtr(arg)
End Function
```

Here, `SetTimer` creates a flag on the queue once it elapses, and `PeekMessage` forces this flag to be evaluated - this lets me destroy the timer, as `KillTimer` does not remove existing messages (and I confirmed this was the case with another peek after the `KillTimer` call - the message was there in the queue)

However once again the output in the immediate window shows the message has not caused the `asyncProc` to run.

```
Scheduling...
Create Timer: 482245352 
syncProc called (should be called first)
```

---

Where my confusion lies is in the following: if I put the call to `KillTimer` in the callback proc instead then everything works fine:

```
Private Sub asyncProc(ByVal HWnd As LongPtr, ByVal message As WindowsMessage, ByVal timerID As LongPtr, ByVal tickCount As Long)
    Debug.Print "asyncProc called (should be called second)"
    KillTimer HWnd, timerID
End Sub
```

outputs

```
Scheduling...
Create Timer: 477790208 
syncProc called (should be called first)
asyncProc called (should be called second)
```

Now as I understand it, the state of the thread's message queue should not change based on when I kill the timer (perhaps the timer will have elapsed again depending on how quickly my code executes, but there is no opportunity for other processes to alter the queue while the thread is busy is there?). Printing the queue confirms it contains one timer message as expected anyway.

---

So what I think is happening is that the WM_TIMER message is somehow being marked as invalid when the timerID it is associated with no-longer corresponds to a live timer. To confirm this I tried the original PostMessage approach, but with a temporary timer to *validate* the ID of the message:

```
Private Function tryScheduleProc(ByVal timerProc As LongPtr, ByVal arg As Object) As Boolean
    Debug.Print "Scheduling..."
    'make a validation timer - this won't expire for a long time
    Debug.Print "Create a validation timer:"; SetTimer(Application.HWnd, objPtr(arg), &H7FFFFFFF, timerProc) 'max interval time
    tryScheduleProc = PostMessage(Application.HWnd, WM_TIMER, objPtr(arg), timerProc)
End Function
```

This works as before

```
Scheduling...
Create a validation timer: 482246472 
syncProc called (should be called first)
asyncProc called (should be called second)
```

...but it is not a great solution as I still need to remember to kill the timer in the callback proc, even though it's not being used to generate messages!

## Conclusion

I assume my issue is with the implementation of the message loop in Excel, or the `DispatchMessage` function. I don't know what either of these looks like internally or if they're documented anywhere - but I think Excel's implementation of the message loop is probably to blame because the [Raymond Chen article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141205-00/?p=43463)  on pretty much exactly this subject (orphaned timer messages) doesn't mention this issue. Also the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dispatchmessage) on `DispatchMessage` says

> The MSG structure must contain valid message values

but I don't think that is saying the timerID must still be around, only that the tagMSG.message must have a valid value (that may be an incorrect interpretation ofc). Also the [answer to that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765273/6609896) would have to be wrong if `DispatchMessage` was to blame. But perhaps the observed behaviour comes from somewhere else entirely - I am very new to WinApi & messages and so am not confident in the conclusions I've drawn.

Anyway, I'm wondering if anyone can shed some light on what's causing this behaviour, and indeed suggest some nice workaround for calling methods immediately after the code has run without too many limitations on what the async or sync methods must look like?

Comment: I can't really explain what is happening, but there is a simple solution that doesn't involve a timer at all. Have `tryScheduleProc` store `timerProc` and `arg` in a list somewhere in memory, then `PostMessage()` a custom message to `Application.HWnd`, and have the message handler simply loop through the list calling the stored procs and removung them from the list.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The message handler you're referring to, is that something I have control of through Excel? If it's the thing I'm calling the "message loop" then I'm not sure I can modify it; I couldn't add in a case to the switch statement which says "On WM_APP + 1 messages do blah...". The reason I'm using Timer messages is because the TimerProc argument allows me to bypass the standard window proc and provide my own handler - if there's another kind of message I can `Post` that lets me provide my own callback then that would be a great alternative. Not sure if that's what you were getting at?

Comment: `WM_TIMER` messages aren't posted to a queue, they're generated on the fly when you call `PeekMessage` or `GetMessage` if a timer has expired and no other messages remain in the queue.

Comment: @JonathanPotter That's not the issue here though I don't think; I've already either (1): Used `PeekMessage` with PM_NOREMOVE to force the flag from the timer to evaluate and place a message in the queue or (2): Used `PostMessage` to put a WM_TIMER message into the queue manually. I can confirm the messages are there by `Kill`ing the timer - that should unset any auto-gen flags - and then `Peek`ing again; either way a message is queued. My issue is that if I go on to `Dispatch` it manually, or let the message loop do it for me, for whatever reason the TIMERPROC is only called if a timer exists.

Comment: @Greedo if you don't control the window you are posting to, you can't edit its existing message handlers, but you can [subclass the window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) to add additional handlers and bypass existing handlers

Comment: @Greedo or, you could simply post your own message with a function pointer in it, similar to `WM_TIMER`, and then have your message handler execute the function directly. No list needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau good ideas I'll take a look

Comment: @IInspectable Hmm, I tried a test and it seems like they are being picked up - I assume you're talking about the instance where I Post a message manually. [Here's the test module.](https://gist.github.com/Greedquest/5d40502b4f03e1e3fc4f2e47d26b085f)

Comment: @IInspectable read Raymond Chen's articles on this subject more carefully. The filtering looks for a real message first, and if no match is found then it checks the flags to generate a matching message. Filtering on `WM_TIMER` will find real messages and generated messages.