# Remove messages by their wparam

Tags: vba, winapi, timer, message-queue

I am trying to remove `WM_TIMER` messages from the message queue according to the `wparam` (timerId) they are associated with. This is because when you destroy a timer, [the messages already in the queue aren't removed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141205-00/?p=43463). This isn't a problem for timers with an `lparam (TIMERPROC)` specified, as for some reason [they are just ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57134016/6609896). However some of my messages are generated with no `TIMERPROC`, and these continue to fire even when their parent timers are dead - [as sometimes they build up in the message queue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160624-00/?p=93745)

So is this a sensible approach:

```
targetID = ...
Do While WinAPI.PeekMessage(MSG, myHWnd, WM_TIMER, WM_TIMER, PM_REMOVE) <> 0
    If MSG.wparam = targetID Then
        'do nothing
    Else
         WinAPI.DispatchMessage MSG 'send it back to the window
    End If
Loop
```

It doesn't feel like a sensible approach but I couldn't work out a way to do this with `PM_NOREMOVE`

Comment: They only build up if you request them and don't remove them. It seems likely to me that you have misdiagnosed your problem.

Comment: The only way for a `WM_TIMER` message to wind up in the message queue is a call to `PeekMessage` with `PM_NOREMOVE`. Looks like your fix created the problem in the first place.

Comment: @IInspectable Are you sure, the way I understood [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160624-00/?p=93745) I linked was that my host application (Excel) was peeking at WM_SYSTIMER messages and that generates the WM_TIMER messages. Although I must admit I assumed that the word COM meant that article was relevant to me, is it not? I'm using a Userform to generate the hWnd for my timers, but Excel is the one managing the thread and hosting whatever weird and wonderful _modal message loop_ that may lead to the issue.

Comment: That sounds implausible. It seems very likely that you have completely misdiagnosed the problem. Perhaps you could tell us about the actual problem rather than your proposed solution.

Comment: I'm sure there's COM involved, somewhere. Office's automation interface is exposed as COM interfaces. I don't know, whether COM is involved in your particular situation. To understand what's really going on, it's probably best if you produced a [mcve].